# How to get the name of a variable isolated from a data.frame using indexing?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

Given a variable isolated from a data frame, how does one obtain it's name?
It needs to work in functions where indexing is done internally (eg. apply).

```
df<-data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10)

names(df[,1])
```

produces:

```
>NULL

test<-df[,1]
test[0]
```

Here is an example where this may be useful:

```
library(plyr)
relabel<-colwise(function(column){
  column<-paste(names(column),column)})
relabel(df)
```

gives

```
data.frame(a=c(.1,.2,.3,...), b=c(.1,.2,...))
```

The desired results would be:

```
data.frame(a=c('a.1','a.2','a.3'), b=c('b.1','b.2', 'b.2'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `drop = FALSE` argument in the indexing as in:

```
df<-data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10)

names(df[,1, drop=FALSE])
```

Here's a function to do what you're looking for:

```
namer.guy <- function(x) paste(rep(names(x), nrow(x)),  unlist(x), sep=".")

namer.guy(df[, 1, drop=F])
```

**Edit: Per Etienne Low-Decarie's request...**

```
namer.guy2 <- function(df){
    name.paster <- function(i) paste(names(df)[i], df[, i], sep=".")
    DF <- data.frame(sapply(seq_along(df), name.paster))
    names(DF) <- names(df)
    return(DF)
}

namer.guy2(df)
```

Comment: Any way this can be applied to my example using colwise (or any other flavour of apply?)

Comment: I added a response but this probably should have been a new post as your original question was answered.

Comment: Thanks for the addition!  The example using colwise was there from the start though.  Appologies if I was not clear enough.